# Как поместить элемент который вылазит за границы блока так, чтобы это было красиво

Tags: frontend, веб-дизайн

Есть корзина товаров и в ней 2 карточки. У первой карточки все в порядке с атрибутами (40, 41, 42, 43). А вот у второй карточки проблемы, атрибуты  слишком длинные. Из-за этого картинка данной карточки сдвинулась за пределы корзины. Как можно красиво вместить атрибуты во второй карточке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так минимальную разметку покажи, а то что мы тут гадать будем на чем ты разметку пишешь(гридах, флексах, бутстрапиш)

Comment: на флексах, но это не важно, код могу переписать. Мне бы хоть какое-то представление дать как это можно поместить

Comment: тогда вынеси атрибуты вниз карточки или сделай фиксированный бокс где пишутся атрибуты, пусть переносятся на вторую строку и далее